# Adding event listener for bookmark related events

Tags: microsoft-edge, event-listener, microsoft-edge-extension

Is there any way I can listen to event when a bookmark is getting added to edge favorites? Looking at the documentation, it appears browser.bookmarks.onCreated is not supported yet in edge. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Sorry! There seems to be no other way to listen for Bookmarks/Favorites getting created on Edge. You shall have to wait for the API implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry! There seems to be no other way to listen for Bookmarks/Favorites getting created on Edge. You shall have to wait for the API implementation.

Here is a nice website to check for API compatibilities :::

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/bookmarks

Latest MS Edge build when this was answered ::: Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0